# Carry/Hold Risk, Rewards

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have a question about the usage of "***carry***" and "***hold***".  According to definition 9 for "***carry***" in this [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/carry):

> definition 9 (carry):  to have (something) as a result or consequence

, and definition 10 for "*hold*" in the same [dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/hold):

> definition 10 (hold):  to have (a specified quality, feature, etc.)

, it seems the following is possibly standard English:

> 1. The plan ***holds*** a lot of risks.
> 2. The plan ***holds*** a lot of benefits.
> 3. The plan ***carries*** a lot of risks.
> 4. The plan ***carries*** a lot of benefits.

But I am not sure.  What do native speakers think?  Are some of the usages  of "*carry*" and "*hold*" in sentences 1 thru 4 wrong?

Comment: What we carry we have in our possession.  Hence, **reward**, that which lies ahead as the benefit of some action, is not something a plan can "carry". We would say "That plan is attended by significant risk" but not "That plan is attended by significant rewards".

Comment: Change **rewards** to **benefits** and the situation changes.

Comment: @TRomano  So, after replacing "**reward**" with "**benefit**", all four sentences are now standard English?

Comment: It's not a matter of "standard" English, @meatie, but of which collocations tend to be avoided and which tend to be favored.  I would avoid "carry lots of rewards' on semantic/stylistic grounds. But there are speakers who treat "rewards" and "benefits" as if they were perfectly synonymous, and they wouldn't blink twice if you said "carry lots of rewards".

Comment: Compare the sentence that has "carries the threat" on this page, which came up in another question here on ELL. http://www.businessinsider.com/why-janet-yellen-could-resign-if-trump-wins-2016-9

Comment: The rumor could "carry the *threat* of a financial crisis" but it could not carry the financial crisis itself. If "reward' is understood to be an outcome, like the crisis, then "rewards" cannot be "carried" any more than a "crisis" can be carried. It is only if we understand "reward" to be something other than an outcome that it can be "carried". For some speakers (in corporate Human Resources departments especially) "rewards" have become synonymous with "ongoing benefits".  If we understand "rewards" to be an outcome, we could say "carries the *promise* of significant rewards".

Answer (score 1):

Why not just go with "has"?

> This plan has many risks.
>
> This plan has many rewards.

"Carries" has a sense of "brings with", e.g. the fleas carry a disease.  So "the plan carries many risks" would be ok.  But I would usually use "holds" for something concrete, e.g. the garage holds 20 trucks.

Comment: @RichardKayser done